How can I mock an "Instance<T>" class to test multiple services of one type in quarkus?
Question:
How can I mock an Instance class with mockito in quarkus?
 Minimal example working before needing to use Instance:
Originally I had a minimal reproducible code working as follows:
I had one interface implemented by a ServiceA class:
public interface ServiceInterface {
    public String getName();
}

@ApplicationScoped
public class ServiceA implements ServiceInterface {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "I am A";
    }
    
}


This was used by a resource:
@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    @Inject
    ServiceInterface service;
    

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        stringBuilder.append(service.getName());

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}


Was working as expected:

And I could write an easy test mocked for it (quarkus-junit5-mockito added to the pom.xml):
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@QuarkusTest
class GreetingResourceTest {
    @InjectMock
    ServiceInterface service;

    @Test
    void testHelloEndpoint() {
        when(service.getName()).thenReturn("I am C");

        given()
                .when().get("/hello")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body(is("I am C"));
    }

}

 Minimal example that shows my problem:
Now I introduced a second service:
@ApplicationScoped
public class ServiceB implements ServiceInterface {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "I am B";
    }
    
}

And I changed my resource to take both services with Instance:

@Path("/hello")
public class GreetingResource {

    @Inject
    Instance<ServiceInterface> services;
    

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String hello() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (ServiceInterface service : services) {
            stringBuilder.append(service.getName());
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}


Testing it produces the expected result:

But I am not able to find a way to rewrite my test.
My attempts:
For example some attempts to solve this issue were:

@QuarkusTest
class GreetingResourceTest {
    @InjectMock
    Instance<ServiceInterface> services;

    @Test
    void testHelloEndpoint() {
        // This is wrong!!!
        when(services.get().getName()).thenReturn("I am C");

        given()
                .when().get("/hello")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body(is("I am C"));
    }

}


@QuarkusTest
class GreetingResourceTest {
    @Mock
    Instance<ServiceInterface> services;
    
    @InjectMock
    ServiceInterface service;

    @Test
    void testHelloEndpoint() {
        // This is wrong!!
        when(services.get()).thenReturn(service);
        when(services.get().getName()).thenReturn("I am C");

        given()
                .when().get("/hello")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body(is("I am C"));
    }

}

But I could not find anything meaningful from the exceptions returned, for example:

Field jakarta.enterprise.inject.Instance<org.acme.service.ServiceInterface> org.acme.GreetingResourceTest.services of class org.acme.GreetingResourceTest is not a producer field, but is annotated with a stereotype: io.quarkus.test.Mock


@Serkan, this would work in this simple scenario. But if instead serviceA is doing an API call to an external service that would not be acceptable for a test. Could you provide an hint how can QuarkusComponentTest be used? I am not able to find anything related to this situation in that link.

I think you want something like the following. Instance<T> implements both Iterable<T> and Provider<T>. Instance::iterator() returns an Iterator<T>, which is what is used by your test where you iterate over services with an enhanced for loop. The idea is that you want to provide the Instance<ServiceInterface> to the class under test, and mock out its iterator() method, and then return either mock or real ServiceInterfaces.
@QuarkusTest
class GreetingResourceTest {
    @InjectMock
    Instance<ServiceInterface> services;

    @Test
    void testHelloEndpoint() {
        List<ServiceInterface> list = List.of(new ServiceA());
        when(services.iterator()).thenReturn(list.iterator());

        given()
                .when().get("/hello")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body(is("I am A"));
    }
}

Or:
@QuarkusTest
class GreetingResourceTest {
    @InjectMock
    Instance<ServiceInterface> services;

    @Test
    void testHelloEndpoint() {
        ServiceInstance service = Mockito.mock(ServiceA.class);
        List<ServiceInterface> list = List.of(service);
        when(services.iterator()).thenReturn(list.iterator());
        when(service.getName()).thenReturn("I am C");

        given()
                .when().get("/hello")
                .then()
                .statusCode(200)
                .body(is("I am C"));
    }
}


I'm not able to make it work that way. If I just write the first line I get a type mismatch: Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<ServiceInterface> to ServiceInterface. If I remove the List.of then I get IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid type: class java.lang.Object if I import @Mock from mockito, or class org.acme.GreetingResourceTest is not a producer field, but is annotated with a stereotype: io.quarkus.test.Mock if I import @Mock from quarkus.

What does Instance<ServiceInterface>::get return? I can't find the Javadocs for it online, but you should be able to hover over it in your IDE and see. Maybe it returns an array?

I found it. Instance<T> is jakarta.enterprise.inject.Instance which implements jakarta.inject.Provider<T> and its get() method just returns a T.

Now that I know what types Instance implements and what I should return, I hope I have gotten closer to a working solution, but I still don't have any way to test it. Please let me know if it works for you.

I still get  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a valid type: class java.lang.Object at runtime of the test

@nck Where do you get that? At what line is the exception thrown?

I'm not really good writing tests, but I think mocking Instance is not the right way to write this test: you are testing you business code which is expected a list of ServiceInterface via Instance so try create a well-known set of objects returned by Instance.get.
You can use QuarkusMock#installMockForType(T mock, Class<? super T> instance, Annotation... qualifiers) which is used to replace bean instances with a mock programmatically:
@Test
void test() {
  var serviceAMock = Mockito.mock(ServiceA.class);
  var serviceBMock = Mockito.mock(ServiceB.class);
  // personalize service mocks and replace them
  QuarkusMock.installMockForType(serviceAMock,ServiceA.class);
  QuarkusMock.installMockForType(serviceBMock,ServiceB.class);
}

Another way is to @InjectMocks for ServiceA and ServiceB or you can write additional @Produces for ServiceInterface.

The problem with this solution is that you have to adjust the test every new service you add to your system. for example serviceC, serviceD...

if the context changes all failed tests should be corrected

This should work:
@A
@ApplicationScoped
public class ServiceA implements ServiceInterface {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "A";
    }
}

@B
@ApplicationScoped
public class ServiceB implements ServiceInterface {

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "B";
    }
}

@Path("/services")
public class ServiceController {

    @Any
    @Inject
    Instance<ServiceInterface> services;

    @GET
    @Produces(TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String names() {
        return this.services.stream()
                .map(ServiceInterface::getName)
                .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
    }
}

@QuarkusTest
class ServiceControllerTest {

    @A
    @InjectMock
    ServiceInterface serviceA;

    @B
    @InjectMock
    ServiceInterface serviceB;

    @Inject
    ServiceController controller;

    @Test
    void foo() {
        when(this.serviceA.getName()).thenReturn("AAA");
        when(this.serviceB.getName()).thenReturn("BBB");

        var result = this.controller.names();
        assertThat(result).containsPattern("(AAA|BBB)");
    }
}

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-junit5-mockito</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

You need to define the qualifiers (@A and @B), otherwise there is no way to mock the services separately.
And unfortunately, doing the same with @QuarkusComponentTest doesn't work.
